# Drupal 7 - Make embedded iFrame full width

Tags: html, css, iframe, drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to figure out a way to make a page go full width (I'm using Drupal 7).

The page has an embedded form on it.

Previously there were two blocks, which when I removed I'd hoped the iframe would fill.

**Current iframe**
[image: Current situation]

**What I'm trying to achieve**
[image: Ideal situation]

How do I go about this? - [Link](http://www.workbooks.com/portal-test)

Answer (score 0):

You should edit your theme's style.css file and remove the following lines (line 481):

```
#right {
    display: block; 
    float: right; 
    width: 740px; 
}
```

You still have an extra block in the left region (region-left-sidebar).

Comment: I have another page which is already full width, so there must be another better way? The full width page is found [here](http://www.workbooks.com/fairusagepolicy)

Comment: On that page the #left sidebar is hidden and the css for the  #right area is also overriden: .page-node-1493 #right {
float: left;
width: 952px;
}